# Where are the packages within an installation DVD?

Tags: debian-installer

I have downloaded Kubuntu 16.04 iso image, mounted it to the system and searched for deb files but there was only 20 deb packages: dkms, fakeroot, grub-efi*...

How does ubuntu installer install packages? In other words, how and where are they stored? For example, If I mount a Centos DVD, I can see all rpm files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEB packages are a transport mechanism, not a runtime medium.  The Ubuntu image has already had the packages installed, so they don't need to explicitly be kept around any more, and in the interest of saving space (and download bandwidth), they're not included in the image.

The package metadata is still stored so that packages can be updated or removed at a later date.  If you want to find the actual debs the image was built from, though, you'll have to go to the Ubuntu archives and download them from there.

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks. However, I didn't get a point clearly: What happens when I want to install a system from DVD without internet connection? Does the installer copy the image to the installation disk? AFAIK, Centos installs all packages via its package manager. If so, what are the benefits of this approach?

Comment: Yes, the files are copied from the DVD, it ends up on the hard drive as if they had been installed from the deb files.

Answer (score 1):

Debian packages aren't packaged with the *iso* image and will downloaded via network during installation. Only the necessary packages come pre-packaged with the image.

The Ubuntu installer gets its packages over the Internet as the installation is being done and will do so based on the selected options made by the user at the time of installation, but it will install comfortably without an Internet connection.

There are different types of ISO images (desktop and server editions) that will come pre-packaged with the needed packages to install that type and any extra packages will or can be installed by the user later on. Size is a great consideration with most ISO images.